# Finding and compiling data from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I regularly receive workbooks from business partners. They all use the same template. What I'd like to do is pull in the partner name (always in the same cell) L1 and the "Totals:"(Column B) for the month which always remain in the same column (column CR), but may change rows based on the number of line items that add up to the total. As you can imagine, going through to manually find and transcribe this information to another workbook in order to get a summary of the past month's activities is tedious and open for error.

Some code that I found on excelvbaisfun.com was designed to combine multiple files, but seems to be for nicely formatted data.

I have never written VBA before, so all help is welcome.

```
Sub getDataFromWbs()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set fso = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)

‘This is where you put YOUR folder name
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(“C:\temp\”)

‘Next available Row on Master Workbook
y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“sheet1”).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

‘Loop through each file in that folder
For Each wbFile In fldr.Files

‘Make sure looping only through files ending in .xlsx (Excel files)
If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = “xlsx” Then

‘Open current book
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)

‘Loop through each sheet (ws)
For Each ws In wb.Sheets
‘Last row in that sheet (ws)
wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

‘Loop through each record (row 2 through last row)
For x = 2 To wsLR
‘Put column 1,2,3 and 4 of current sheet (ws) into row y of master sheet, then increase row y to next row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“sheet1”).Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1) ‘col 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“sheet1”).Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(x, 2)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“sheet1”).Cells(y, 3) = CDate(ws.Cells(x, 3))
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“sheet1”).Cells(y, 4) = ws.Cells(x, 4)
y = y + 1
Next x

Next ws

‘Close current book
wb.Close
End If

Next wbFile

End Sub
```

Comment: If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = “xlsx” Then  to  If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile) = “xlsx” Then

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the forum.
There are many missing factors that make your question difficult to answer outright, but we are here to try and help.

Your question is definitely achievable in excel using VBA, but would require a thorough understanding of where the total figures need to be pulled from and where the resulting data needs to be copied to, which isn't necessarily mentioned in your question.

What I have done is put together a sample with 3 customer sheets and one master.
The output is placed in the master sheet, and the macro should be run from here.

This should help give you the foundations as an example of what you are trying to do.

Download [this sample file](http://www.amicableits.com/stackexchange/vba_sample.zip).
Copy the folder to your c drive and open the master_monthly_calculator.xlsm.

Enable the Developer Tab, by clicking File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon and check Developer and ok.
[image: Developer Tab]

Then Hit Developer-> Macros and run the get_totals macro and see it in action. You can also view the macro by hitting "Edit".

[image: Macros]

What's going on under the hoods?
The macro is opening all customer sheets in the same folder and searching for the word "Total" in column A. It grabs the total figure and the partner ID and pastes the results in the Master Sheet.

Good Luck,
Peter H

Comment: Thank you Peter, this has been extremely helpful. I was able to edit for my purposes and it works for a test file that I'd set up, but not on the original reports that I am trying to pull from. Here is a [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fxPtgBmtGNwUNdEvPn1QfC1cHDQ9dLq2/view) of one of those files. I'm not sure if is the merged cells that are throwing things off, but ultimately I am looking to pull Cell CR77.

Comment: @DaveR in your sample The Partner Name is in Cell L3.Just update the macro with partner_name = Range("L3").Value ..... this will pull the name BOXSCORE...For the totals.. I'm a little confused, Cell CR77 has the value of 9 which is the Net Leases total is this the figure you want in the master?